# Issues with Rendering Python Script in Django

Tags: python, django

Here are two functions I have in my views.py function in Django.

```
def test():


    return "Hello World" 


def HelloWorld(request):

    return render(request, test())
```

This should correctly render the python script in django, however I get this error: TemplateDoesNotExist. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using render() then you have to return a html file that is inside your /templates folder, otherwise you'll have to return a http response instead:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
def HelloWorld(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```